# How to write "$k$ is equal to any integer" in symbols?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

How do you state that $k$ is equal to any integer in the following?

> The solutions to this equation
>   $$2\sin(3x)-1=0$$
>   are
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> x=\dfrac{\pi}{18}+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}k\\[4pt] 
> x=\dfrac{5\pi}{18}+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}k \\  
> \end{array} 
> \right.
> $$

Comment: You mean $k\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What is Z?  Because its a homework assignment, usually I see teachers that make a complicated such as "All Real Numbers" into a short mathematical line.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers.

Comment: For instance express an even number as $x = 2k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thanks to everybody who answered, and commented, and helped in any way on this post!!! :)

Comment: As for wording, we don't usually say "k is equal to any integer" but instead say "where k may be any integer" or "where k is an integer".  It's a style point.  I'm not sure if I can explain why "k is equal to any integer" is wrong but it does sound to my ear.... a bit off...  But the notation is, as everyone has pointed out $k \in \mathbb Z$ which means, literally, "k is in the set of integers" which means "k is an integer".

Comment: Maybe I'll throw in a minor comment: the "$\mathbb{Z}$" comes from German and is an abbreviation of "Zahle", which simply means "integer". The symbol is used internationally, so any professional mathematician in any country will use it. Although, at least in my country, in school there's an absurd tendency to keep things _too_ simple by denoting the set of integers with "$\mathbb{C}$" which is said to be an abbreviation of "integer" in my language (yup, dumb). Then students in their 1st year solve an equation as above and write $k\in\mathbb{C}$ and are surprised when asked "why k is complex?".

Comment: @corey979 That is actually (not lying here) pretty interesting to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to say that $k$ can be any integer and you want to use symbols, then
$$\huge
k\in \mathbb{Z}
$$
is a standard choice. Here $\mathbb{Z}$ means the set of integers and $\in$ means "belongs to" or "in". That is $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ means that $k$ belongs to the set of integers.

Comment: Do I just draw a capital z, or do I write it like the Z is there?

Comment: @Sigma6RPU: I would write it like it is here. So you write a normal Z with an extra line on the neck

Comment: BTW, its LaTeX code is `\mathbb Z` ($\mathbb Z$).

Answer (score 2):

You have the equation

$$\sin 3x=\frac12\iff \begin{cases}3x=\frac\pi6+2k\pi\\\text{or}\\3x=\frac{5\pi}6+2k\pi\end{cases}\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\iff$$$${}$$

$$\iff x=\frac\pi{18}+\frac23k\pi\;,\;\;\text{or}\;\;x=\frac{5\pi}{18}+\frac23k\pi\;\;,\;\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Comment: I think the OP was just asking about notation?

Comment: @Thomas Perhaps, but then he got more than he bargained for...:)

Comment: Thanks I was just looking how to express the k mathematically because I didn't want to write out the integers part.

Comment: I don't think so. I think you should add a comment about the notation. You use $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ without saying what it means.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU You can write as above or, if you want to be a little more specific, write it as in the answer of Emilio

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Solving 
$$
\sin (3x)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
we have:
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi \quad \mbox{or}\quad x=\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi
$$
with $k=0,\pm 1,\pm2,\cdots$ is a an integer and the terms$+2k\pi$ represent the periodicity of the $\sin $ function . So ....

Comment: I think the OP was asking about notation.